# Как лучше переписать вызов нескольких .replace()?

Tags: python, строки

Нужно сделать замену 3-и и более раз. Как правильнее переписать конструкцию:

```
.get_text(separator=' ').replace('\n', '').replace('  ', '').replace('|', '')
```

Comment: Для данного случая: `'|'.join(text.split())`

Answer (score 6):

Можно также воспользоваться [str.maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) + [str.translate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) - это один самых быстрых способов заменить или удалить одновременно много символов в строке. Для удаления мы просто заменяем символы на пустую строку.

```
s = "Hello |  world|!"

tran_tab = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(list("\n ,|"), ""))
res = s.translate(tran_tab)

print(res)
>>> Helloworld!
```

или универсальным средством - регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

res = re.sub(r"[\s,|]", "", s)
print(res)
>>> Helloworld!
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```
s = "Hello |  world|!"
for r in (('\n', ''), ('  ', ''), ('|', '')):
    s = s.replace(*r)
print(s)
```

Выход:

```
Hello world!
```